# Apache Default Proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have an internal web server (192.168.1.2) that manage multiple domains.
Now i need to put in DMZ one more server, acting as reverse proxy (it's an Apache 2.2.3, with IP 192.168.1.3 and one more interface with static internet IP)

I need this Apache server should proxy any domain coming from internet to my internal web server except for one domain (this.example.com)

A sort of schema:

```
INTERNET->Apache Proxy->Internal Web server (default for any domain)
INTERNET->Apache Proxy->Differente Web Server (this.example.com)
```

What kind of configuration do i have to setup on this Apache Proxy? I read about Proxypass and similar string, but i didn't understand how to proxy "the default" to my internal web server...

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is working on "defaults", but domain this.example.com does not work...

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine     On
    RewriteRule       ^(.*)$        http://192.168.1.2$1  [P]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    LogLevel warn
        ServerName this.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        #AllowOverride None
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```